# NODE_ENV in windows powershell returns undefined

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, command-line

Windows path is set to nodejs. However I cannot read the process.env.NODE_ENV **unless** using Command Prompt AS Admin.

I want to be able to set and read NODE_ENV in Windows powershell.

Comment: PowerShell can read and set environment variables. Why do you believe this is not the case? (Describe the problem, not your interpretation of the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables can be set on 3 levels in Windows `Machine`, `User`, `Process`, which are inheriting from parent processes when the child-process starts. Of course `User` level ones only inherits if the process running in that user's context.

On the other hand, if the parent process (eg: *System*) changes a variable, these changes are not propagated automatically to already running child-processes (eg: *PowerShell*, or `node`), unless you **restart** these.

With this sense PowerShell also automatically inherits env-vars, which you can see under the `env:` PSDrive:

```
ls env:\*
```

If you can't see the new variable and you would like to avoid a restart, you can also use `[System.Environment]` .NET class to read and populate this in an already running console, eg:

```
$env:NODE_ENV = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('NODE_ENV',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```